# How to create an endpoint out of a tensorflow project

Tags: api, rest, tensorflow

Very new to tensorflow. I found this cool project which you can upload a bird photo to and it will identify the bird specie type. It can be found here:

https://tfhub.dev/google/aiy/vision/classifier/birds_V1/1

Any ideas how I can make an endpoint out of this so that I could POST a photo to and receive bird type as a response

Answer (score 0):

You can get pre trained from the tensorflow using

```
# Import pre-trained bird classification model from Tensorflow Hub 
URL = 'https://tfhub.dev/google/aiy/vision/classifier/birds_V1/1'           
bird = hub.KerasLayer(URL, input_shape=(224,224,3))
model=tf.keras.Sequential([bird])
model.summary()
```

After getting the model you can pass the image to the model which you want to predict. Before passing the image to the model you have to convert the image into a numpy array.

```
bird=np.array(bird)/255.0
```

Then you can make predictions using

```
result=np.argmax(model.predict(bird[np.newaxis,...]))
```

Please refer to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/kiransair/9d2ad4f93e27cc9f205345174f8d245b) for complete code. Thank You.